# Optimize this code which keeps values in an array if they match a given range, and nearby values also match the given range, removing all other values

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, filtering

I wrote this script to iterate through an array, and only keep values if the number is between 40 and 60, and either the previous three or next three values are also between 40 and 60. The code does what its supposed to but seems clunky and inefficient. Is there a better way to write this?

```
my_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 51, 49, 56, 44, 60, 70, 80, 55, 90]

output_list = list(my_list)
n = 0
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if not 40 < value < 60: 
        output_list.pop(index-n)
        n+=1
    else: 
        a_count = 0
        b_count = 0
        for i in range(3):
            try: 
                if 40 < my_list[index + i + 1] < 60: 
                    a_count += 1
            except IndexError: 
                pass
            try: 
                if 40 < my_list[index - i - 1] < 60: 
                    b_count += 1
            except IndexError: 
                pass
        if a_count != 3 and b_count != 3: 
            output_list.pop(index-n)
            n+=1

print(output_list)
```

I tried to do it without creating the duplicate list, but its the only way to have a reference list while removing items from the output list. Also it seems redundant to iterate through values which were already tested when I tested values ahead of the current one, but I feel that will make it more convoluted and prone to errors. Overall I am unsure how to make it less clunky, but I am sure it is possible. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean "all of the surrounding six values" or "any of the surrounding six values" or "either on the left or right side but not both"?

Comment: We don't do general "optimize this code" requests here: Stack Overflow is only for narrow, specific problems. Our sister site [codereview.se] is better suited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a list comprehension like

```
my_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 51, 49, 56, 44, 60, 70, 80, 55, 90]

new_list = [
    value
    for i, value in enumerate(my_list)
    if (
        40 < value < 60  # if the value is between 40 and 60
        and (
            # exactly three in-range values on the left..?
            sum(1 for j in range(i - 3, i) if j >= 0 and 40 < my_list[j] < 60) == 3
            # ..or exactly three in-range values on the right?
            or sum(1 for j in range(i + 1, i + 4) if j < len(my_list) and 40 < my_list[j] < 60) == 3
        )
    )
]

print(new_list)
```

Comment: If you check `i` first, the rest gets simpler: `i >= 3 and all(40 < x < 60 for x in my_list[i-3:i])`

Answer (score 0):

Checking each element only once:

```py
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 51, 49, 56, 44, 60, 70, 80, 55, 90]

output_list = []
for between, [*group] in groupby(my_list, lambda x: 40 < x < 60):
    if between:
        del group[-3:3]
        output_list += group

print(output_list)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDPCoJAEMbpuvfuc8zawPJPJvkkIqG41oK6yzaSPkuXLvVQPU1jpjjwY5iZ5fuW7_HWHV5V_Xy-Giy2wWexLIyqQKIwqFR5A1lpZRAuRjU66xirunMpbwgRxDaHHbEnHMIlvJ49saP5SN2n7nLwaX8ggv7ucTjaCWOqQd3gJJewQhnIBN6FqDnE659nArIe3Vd_cw5lWmV5Cm1IrnCClvBtK2RAJYtRZJj7ykU5iMRbJ3SSaT__wiYanjCmjaxxNbtZQzr_kMawvg)

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the given code, you can use list comprehension and avoid unnecessary pop operations, which can be inefficient. Here's an optimized version of the code:

```
my_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 51, 49, 56, 44, 60, 70, 80, 55, 90]

output_list = []

# Counter 
n = 0

for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    # Check if the value is not within the range (40, 60)
    if not 40 < value < 60:
        n += 1
    else:
        # Count the number of valid elements within a range of 3 elements after and before the current index
        a_count = sum(1 for i in range(1, 4) if index + i < len(my_list) and 40 < my_list[index + i] < 60)
        b_count = sum(1 for i in range(1, 4) if index - i >= 0 and 40 < my_list[index - i] < 60)
        
        # Check if both the forward and backward counts are not equal to 3
        if a_count != 3 and b_count != 3:
            # If not, increment the skip counter
            n += 1
        else:
            # If the value and its surrounding elements meet the criteria
            output_list.append(value)

print(output_list)
```

Comment: You say list comprehension but you don't have any...

Comment: What's the point of your `n`? You're not using it